# DD Bash backup issues - "unrecognized operand"

Tags: linux, bash, dd, pipe

I’m using the [Datto Block Driver](https://github.com/datto/dattobd) to take snapshots of my running server every night. After the snapshot is taken, I `dd` the snapshot from `/dev/datto0` through PipeViewer (`pv`) and `gzip` to a file on the file system. The file is then uploaded to DropBox and deleted.

I have automated this with a Bash script and set it to run via a cron job every night. Here is the snippet of my Bash script that is giving me troubles:

```
echo "$(date +"%r"): Calculating MD5 checksum of /dev/datto0..."
MD5=$(md5sum /dev/datto0)
echo "$(date +"%r"): MD5: $MD5"

echo "$(date +"%r"): Compressing /dev/datto0 via gzip to /tmp directory..."
dd if=/dev/datto0 | pv | gzip -1 | dd of=/tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz

echo "$(date +"%r"): Compression complete. File size is: $(du -b /tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz | cut -f1) bytes"
```

Here’s the error that is being thrown:

```
02:37:35 PM: Calculating MD5 checksum of /dev/datto0...
02:54:01 PM: MD5: 28a6a6c11f088d6149d178af6e45102a  /dev/datto0
02:54:01 PM: Compressing /dev/datto0 via gzip to /tmp directory...
dd: unrecognized operand ‘/dev/datto0.dd.gz’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.
 896kB 0:00:00 [42.7MB/s] [  <=>                                                                                                      ]
du: cannot access ‘/tmp/BACKUP_09_21_2015_28a6a6c11f088d6149d178af6e45102a’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/dev/datto0.dd.gz’: No such file or directory
02:54:01 PM: Compression complete. File size is:  bytes
```

Here is the part of the error that is really making me scratch my head:

```
dd: unrecognized operand ‘/dev/datto0.dd.gz’
```

Not once in my script am I referring to `/dev/datto0.dd.gz`

Maybe part of my `dd` command is being skipped for some reason? `dd: unrecognized operand ‘/dev/datto0.dd.gz’`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the output from `md5sum` includes both the hash value and the original filename, so the variable MD5 gets set to something like `28a6a6c11f088d6149d178af6e45102a  /dev/datto0`. Thus the command

```
dd of=/tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz
```

expands to

```
dd of=/tmp/BACKUP_09_21_2015_28a6a6c11f088d6149d178af6e45102a /dev/datto0.dd.gz
```

...which confuses `dd` a great deal. Similarly, when you use `> /tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz`, it expands to two words, the shell isn't sure which to send output to, and it gives an "ambiguous redirect" error.

You could solve this by piping `md5sum`'s output through `awk '{print $1}'`:

```
MD5=$(md5sum /dev/datto0 | awk '{print $1}')
```

...or by using the variable expansion `${MD5%% *}`, which will trim the first space and everything after it. Also, it's generally a good idea to keep variable references inside double-quotes -- it avoids a lot of weird parsing issues like this. Combining this with [Giacomo1968's answer](https://superuser.com/a/976131/167207) gives:

```
dd if=/dev/datto0 | pv | gzip -1 > "/tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5%% *}.dd.gz"
```

Answer (score 1):

This `dd` command looks odd. Why is there an `dd if` on one side of pipes and a `dd of` on the other side of the pipes?

```
dd if=/dev/datto0 | pv | gzip -1 | dd of=/tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz
```

Based on [the advice given on this page](http://www.linuxweblog.com/dd-image) on using `dd` for backup purposes, it seems your command should be something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/datto0 | pv | gzip -1 > /tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz
```

Note how the last `| dd of=` is now just a simple redirect of output via a right arrow (`>`).

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I gave this a try. Still getting an error, but it's a new one: `./backup.sh: line 61: /tmp/BACKUP_${TODAY}_${MD5}.dd.gz: ambiguous redirect
   0B 0:00:00 [   0B/s] [<=>`